# file.fail() в проверке ввода ругается при считывании матрицы из файла

Tags: c++, матрицы, файловый-ввод-вывод

Написал алгоритм вывода матрицы в программу. По заданию у меня должны быть прописаны различные проверки, чтобы при открытии файла с некорректными данными матрица не заполнялась дальше и программа не крашилась, а просто уведомляла пользователя о некорректном вводе. Вот "проблемная" часть кода:

```
if (file_in.is_open())
{
    int max_num = 0;
    int min_num = 0;
    int cell_width;
    int signs_num = 2;
    
    int tmp, count = 0;
    while (!file_in.eof()) 
    {
        file_in >> tmp;
        if (file_in.fail())
        {
            cout << "Данные записаны некорректно." << endl;
            //correct_input = false;
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }
    file_in.clear();
    file_in.seekg(0);
    char symb;
    tmp = 0;
    while (!file_in.eof()) 
    {
        file_in.get(symb);
        if (file_in.fail())
        {
            cout << "Данные записаны некорректно." << endl;
            correct_input = false;
            break;
        }
        if (symb == ' ')
            tmp++;
        if (symb == '\n') 
            break;
    }
    file_in.clear();
    file_in.seekg(0);
    int rows = count / tmp;
    int cols = tmp;

    int **matrix = new int*[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new int[cols];
    }

    //заполнение матрицы из файла:
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            file_in >> matrix[i][j];
            if (matrix[i][j] > max_num)
                max_num = matrix[i][j];
            if (matrix[i][j] < min_num)
                min_num = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    if (correct_input == true)
    {
        cell_width = the_longest_num(max_num, min_num) + signs_num;
        system("cls");
        cout << "Данные из Вашего файла: " << endl;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                cout << setw(cell_width) << matrix[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Дело в том, что при не закомментированном "correct_input = false;" при первом считывании программа как раз выдает "данные записаны некорректно" при работе с абсолютно корректным файлом. Закомментировал - заработало, матрица полностью считалась и вывелась на экран. Я не очень понимаю, почему это происходит и как это исправить, потому что проверка ввода мне все же нужна.

Comment: [C++ / распространенные ошибки](https://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread1260162.html)

Comment: если коротко, то `eof` проверяет только бит флагов состояния. а устанавливается он при неудачном чтении.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилась проблема изменения первого вайла вот таким вот образом. Если я верно понял, дело было в том, что на последнем символе файла eof "давал добро" на дальнейшее считывание, оно происходило, "каретка" перемещалась в пустоту и тогда уже fail начинал ругаться. Поменял их местами, помогло.

```cpp
while (true) 
{
    file_in >> tmp;
    if (file_in.eof())
        break;
    if (file_in.fail())
    {
        cout << "Данные записаны некорректно." << endl;
        correct_input = false;
        break;
    }
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Вы можете пойти ещё дальше и писать вот так `while (file_in >> tmp) {} if (file_in.fail()) {ups();}`